# Java/Hibernate Beginner Question understanding below code

Tags: java, hibernate

```
package com.util;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception to track it
            System.err.println("SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Optional but can be used to Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

I'm trying to understand the above code. I'm a beginner in Java and having difficulty in understanding specifically the below line. Does this mean, a `Configuration` object has a configure method and configure method has `buildSessionFactory` method?

```
return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods don’t have methods, methods return objects and those objects have methods.

Here, Configuration has a bunch of methods that return Confuguration (so the method is returning the object it is called on).  That allows method chaining, so that configure is called on that object, then buildSessionFactory is called on the same object.

A more common example of method chaining is the java.lang.StringBuilder class. You can build up a string with successive append calls on the same builder object:

```
String example = new StringBuilder(“hello”)
    .append(“ “)
    .append(“world”)
    .toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Configuration object has a configure method which returns the all the configuration specified in hibernate.cfg.xml as a Configuration object. this information is used to connect to the database.
2. Then from configuration object we are taking the SessionFactory object which will be used to creat the session objects to connect to the database.

> Configuration configuration =null; SessionFactory factory=null;
>
> configuration =new
>   Configuration().configure("com/app/cfgs/hibernate.cfg.xml");
>   factory=cfg.buildSessionFactory();